# Is there a way to update GUI or use GUI while CPU is working?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, user-interface, asynchronous

The GUI of my program freezes while the program is doing its work. I created a mass import which can send X-thousand datarows via a called webservice into a database. The code is already very big and I cannot rewrite it for multithreading purpose.

I don't know how to do it. Any suggestions? If needed I will show some code, but at the moment I don't know what to show.

Comment: if you need info on invoking methods in another thread, i answered that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865541/modify-a-control-winforms-through-another-thread/23872904#23872904 also see @Jon Skeet's comment for another possible approach.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you *should* rewrite it to use avoid synchronously doing this on the UI thread. If you do a lot of work on the UI thread, it simply *will* freeze the UI thread. There are a few options here:

- If your web service proxy supports asynchronous calls, and if you're using VB 11, you can use Async / Await to call the web service asynchronously from the UI thread in an asynchronous method, and control will return *back* to the UI thread at the same point in the asynchronous method when the call has completed. It takes a little while to get your head round asynchrony, but this is probably the best option if it's possible.
- You can use the Task Parallel Library to make calls on a different thread, but then you'll need to think carefully about how that thread is going to interact with your UI thread.
- You can use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) to run some code on another thread, but report progress and completion back on the UI thread
- You could *potentially* call [`Application.DoEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) between each web service call, to let the UI handle events. **This is dangerous** - it can lead to *re-entrant* code, so locks won't behave as you expect them to, and similar hard-to-diagnose errors. This should be your last option, if all else fails.

Comment: Hi Jon, thx for your help. Thx for the help at the moment I have .DoEvents implemented. But it doesnt work well. What do you think about following idea: Instead of rewriting the full code,  I add a form which runs in another thread and this form has the options which are needed, like break or pause?

Comment: @steve: I don't know exactly what you mean - I would definitely stick to one UI thread. Asynchronous web service calls are probably the best option, followed by putting them in a different thread, ideally using tasks.